# MongoDB 2.6 runCommand to create a view returns an empty view

Tags: mongodb

Just trying to create a very simple view on MongoDB 2.6 via `mongo` cli.

Following the official documentation at: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/create/#dbcmd.create

I've created an example collection called `survey` with the following documents:

```
{ _id: 1, empNumber: "abc123", feedback: { management: 3, environment: 3 }, department: "A" }
{ _id: 2, empNumber: "xyz987", feedback: { management: 2, environment: 3 }, department: "B" }
{ _id: 3, empNumber: "ijk555", feedback: { management: 3, environment: 4 }, department: "A" }
```

Just to be sure, `db.survey.find()` shows the three document inside the collection.

Since I'm using version 2.6 and not version 3.4, I cannot use the new `createView` wrapper, but following the example I've simply issued this command:

```
db.runCommand ( {
   create: "managementFeedback",
   viewOn: "survey",
   pipeline: [ { $project: { "management": "$feedback.management", 
department: 1 } } ]
} )
```

The above commands just returns `{ "ok" : 1 }`, that states it has succeded, and yet `db.managementFeedback.find()` returns absolutely nothing.

To be sure che pipeline is correct, I issued the following command:

```
db.survey.aggregate({ $project: { "management": "$feedback.management", department: 1 } })
```

so the same pipeline as the previous command, but without creating the view, and it returns correctly the following output:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "department" : "A", "management" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 3, "department" : "A", "management" : 3 }
{ "_id" : 2, "department" : "B", "management" : 2 }
```

I confess I'm a bit confused: why did the pipeline work in the simple `aggregate` command and not in the creation of the view?

I've tryed other simple collections, always zero records in the view.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 does not support views, this is a new feature in MongoDB 3.4. You can see this at the top of the [MongoDB Views Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/index.html) where it says:

> New in version 3.4.

In general, the documentation lists the version in which a feature was added, but it can get kind of murky as you point out with the documentation for the `create` command.

The reason the command is returning `{ "ok" : 1 }` is that the `create` command is simply creating a collection called `managementFeedback`. The command doesn't know to even look at the other fields, so they're simply ignored.

Comment: Yes, that must be the reason. I've been misled by the apparently positive response of the command, maybe it should return some kind of error message instead of `{ "ok": 1 }`. I think I'll try to move to a newer version of MongoDB. Thank you, Pete.

Comment: Confirmed: on a different system, MongoDB v4.0.5, the same code works perfectly.